# Validate / restrict hidden fields for modification

Tags: php, html, web

**Problem**

I am developing an application (in PHP) in which, I will show the user a report of some derived values based on previous entries he had done and the user will check for correctness - if correct, then the user can press *Save* button to submit it to database. Otherwise, the user should be able to edit previous entries, but he should not be able to change derived values in that report.

For that purpose, I have enclosed these values in a hidden input field, so a normal user can not alter these values, but if web developers could inspect the element in their browser and change these values.

Can we prevent these type of attack? If so, how?

**My thoughts**

I can make a string of all hidden fields, encrypt it and save in another hidden field - after postback I can cross-verify actual value and encrypted value.

Is this the correct way to achieve this? and how to do this 
 What do you think?

Comment: have you thought of using session variables instead of using form fields?

Comment: @wribit Thanks i did not think that way , nice idea btw would it cause any problem on server storage if i need to pass around 30 values, would it be better? or cause any overhead?

Comment: it would cause overhead if many users (say 100+) were to be logged at once, requiring the same session variables - sure... but for your worries, I think it's a solution worthy of the slight risk.

Comment: @wribit just in case user open same form in two different tab for different data , then session var be overwrite by each other

Comment: if this is something that you wish them to be able to do - then session variables isn't the answer, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to get a good idea of what you are trying to do but perhaps a solution could be to display a form with input fields disabled (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) then have at the bottom of your page e.g. Is this information correct? .. Then 1 option to Save, and one option for No/Edit. Then do an `if(isset($_POST['edit'])) { .. run form again but with input fields not disabled }`

Only have your SQL update code in the 'edit' section of the code, and have a seperate SQL update code for the save section which just moves the values from wherever you are grabbing them from, to wherever they need to be.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If there are derived values that you need to fill out your form, but don't want to use hidden fields - I suggest using session variables that would contain those derived values as needed. Depending on how many of these forms there are, and how many users will be using them - the overhead is usually negligible with this number of fields (in the 30s)... if you discard them when not needed of course.

Comment: suppose user open data in one tab for case1 then session var will for that , in another tab he open data for case2 then all session var case 2, no matter which forms SAVE button he will press it will save for case 2 only

Comment: yes, I see now - then the only way I can think of is through hidden fields as you've done - but to encrypt their contents.

Comment: can u suggest better encryption technique for this